# app is not deploying if <context> defined outside of server.xml in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

`<context>` works just fine if I define it within `<host>` in server.xml but if I create a file called `manager.xml` in `conf/Catalina/localhost`, the application is not getting deployed. Am I missing anything ?

Here is the `manager.xml`

```
<Context path="/manager" docBase="/var/tomcat/webapps/manager" privileged="true">
  </Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was due to deployonStartup is set to false. I have changed this to true and I'm able to use context.xml outside of war file now.